# mySQLi SELECT in PHP with another table's IVs for decrypting table column data

Tags: php, select, encryption, mysqli, mcrypt

I have two tables, which will eventually exist on different databases, but for now I just want to concentrate on getting this to work on one. I have one table, which we can call 'A' that has encrypted information using mcrypt, but as base64 encoded values. Every row has a separate IV associated with it stored on another table which we can call 'B'.

If I want to do a SELECT statement in php to get all the US states that equal "Ohio" after being decrypted in table A, how would I do this and at the same time get it to select using every row in table B to provide the IV for decryption?

For clarification:

Table A:

ID | encrypted value

Table B:

ID | IV

ID on table A is associated with ID on table B.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tablename as a INNER JOIN othertable as b ON a.id = b.id`

Comment: I don't store the IV on table A. The only things that are shared are their ID's.

Comment: It's the same concept, you just need to format the query to fit your database. If you gave generic layout/data information about the tables then I can change my original comment to better fit your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the info iam-decoder. I updated my question with the table layout. Do I still use the same method? I don't see how I can if I'm using WHERE STATE='something' if the state is encrypted differently for every row.

Comment: Your question states "Every column has a separate IV associated with it..." - seriously? Every column or every row?

Comment: Thank you for catching that RamRaider! My bad.. It's every row.

Comment: How is `IV` used to decrypt the values?

Comment: Barmer - It's part of PHP's mcrypt_encrypt/mcrypt_decrypt functions. It's the vector (IV) that's used to encrypt the data, along with a key. I use the mcrypt_create_iv function to create the IV. I'll investigate your answer more soon. Thanks.

Comment: You need to use `@` before a username to notify them that you replied to the comment. And spell the name correctly, which should be easy because it does completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables and pass the encrypted value and the corresponding IV to the decryption function.

```
SELECT a.id, decrypt(a.encrypted_value, b.iv) AS state
FROM tableA as a
JOIN tableB as b ON a.id = b.id
HAVING state = 'Ohio'
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. What is the decrypt part, and shouldn't there be a WHERE clause?

Comment: I didn't know what you're using for encryption/decryption, so I put `decrypt` in as a placeholder. If you're doing the encryption in PHP rather than MySQL, then this answer won't work. You'll need to return everything from the `JOIN`, and loop over the results calling `mcrypt_decrypt` in PHP until you find `Ohio`.